# Execute vbs script (that does double hop) in remote windows machine from linux using Pywinrm

Tags: python, winrm, credssp

I need to run a vbs script in Windows machine from a Linux machine. I used Pywinrm to achieve the connection between Windows and Linux. The vbs script has a set of installation in it. Is there anyway I can run this vbs script without having to use "CredSSP" authentication?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use kerberos in a double hop scenario initiated using pywinrm.  A minor patch needs to be made to pywinrm in order to get forwardable kerberos tickets, which is outlined here:
https://github.com/diyan/pywinrm/issues/58

You will need to perform SPN registration as needed for the services you are connecting to on the second hop.  You'll also need to configure the computer account of the first hop to be trusted for delegation to the desired services using kerberos.

Good luck!